# How can I print my output at a new line in PL/SQL Web document?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I print my output at a new line in PL/SQL Web document?

For learning PL/SQL Web, I try to make a web page to display the list. I make this code to testing:

```
create or replace procedure aptstaff_information_prn as
begin
htp.print('<html><head>');
htp.print('<title>Staff Apartment Details</title></head><body>');
htp.print('<p>Staff Apartment Details</p>');
for Apt_staff in
(select staff.first_name as sfn, staff.last_name as sln, staff.position as sp, rental.rental_no as srn
 from staff left join rental
 on staff.staff_no = rental.staff_no
 order by staff.first_name, staff.last_name, staff.position)
loop
if Apt_staff.srn is not null then
htp.prn(Apt_staff.sfn||' '||Apt_staff.sln||'      '||Apt_staff.sp);
htp.prn('--------------------');
htp.prn('Apartment#');
htp.prn(Apt_staff.srn);
else
htp.prn(Apt_staff.sfn||' '||Apt_staff.sln||'      '||Apt_staff.sp);
htp.prn('--------------------');
htp.prn('Apartment#');
htp.prn('No Apartment Rented');
end if;
end loop;
htp.print('</body></html>');
end;
```

I really get a successful Procedure and test it successfully. However, the output is that like this:

```
Ann Tremble Assistant--------------------Apartment#100104Joe White Assistant--------------------Apartment#100106Joe White Assistant--------------------Apartment#100101Julia Roberts Assistant--------------------Apartment#100103Susan Brandon Supervisor--------------------Apartment#No Apartment RentedTerry Ford Manager--------------------Apartment#100102Terry Ford Manager--------------------Apartment#100105
```

It did not print output in a new line, I want to print output like this:

```
Ann Tremble Assistant
--------------------
Apartment#
100104
```

What should I make a new line for my output? Can I use `chr(13)||chr(10)` or use `<br>`to make a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include [HTP.BR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_htp.htm#ARPLS70465) calls when necessary.

```
This procedure generates the <BR> tag which begins a new line of text. 
It performs the same operation as the NL Procedure.
```

---

```
<snip>
LOOP
  IF Apt_staff.srn IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     HTP.prn (
        Apt_staff.sfn || ' ' || Apt_staff.sln || '      ' || Apt_staff.sp);
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn ('--------------------');
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn ('Apartment#');
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn (Apt_staff.srn);
  ELSE
     HTP.prn (
        Apt_staff.sfn || ' ' || Apt_staff.sln || '      ' || Apt_staff.sp);
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn ('--------------------');
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn ('Apartment#');
     htp.br;
     HTP.prn ('No Apartment Rented');
  END IF;
END LOOP;
<snip>
```